# Landweber-exactness type theorems for arbitrary morphisms of $E_\infty$-ring spectra

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, cohomology

This question comes out of a join of [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/406871/does-the-witten-genus-determine-mathrmtmf-or-mathrmtmf) and [this other question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/392678/on-the-comparison-map-mu-bulletx-otimes-mu-bulletpte-bulletpt-to-e) of mine, so please remove it as a duplicate if you feel it is so (to my eyes it puts the two previous ones in a context of larger generality and sets a question I find of interest in its own, but I would not complain in case it is flagged as a duplicate). In what follows everything could more generally and possibly more naturally be expressed in terms of homology modules over cohomology, but I will write in cohomological terms to keep the question more immediate. For the same reason the question is somehow approximate here and there, I apologize for this.

Given a morphism of $E_\infty$-ring spectra $\rho:A\to B$ we have, for any finite CW-complex $X$, a natural commutative diagram of rings
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
A^\bullet(pt) @>>> A^\bullet(X)\\
@V V V @VV V\\
B^\bullet(pt) @>>> B^\bullet(X)
\end{CD}
where $A^\bullet$ and $B^\bullet$ denote the multiplicative cohomology theories associate with $A$ and $B$. Then, by the universal property of the tensor product of rings, we have a comparison map
$$
A^\bullet(X)\otimes_{A^\bullet(pt)}B^\bullet(pt)\to B^\bullet(X).
$$
and it is tempting to call $\rho$ a Landweber exact morphism if the comparison map is an isomorphism for any finite CW-complex $X$. Ultimately, the comparison map only depends on the ring morphism $\rho(pt):A^\bullet(pt)\to B^\bullet(pt)$, so Landweber exactness of $\rho$ should ultimately be a property of $\rho(pt)$. Additionally, if $R$ is an arbitrary ring and $\rho_R: A^\bullet(pt)\to R$ is a morphism of rings, we can form
$$
A^\bullet(X)\otimes_{A^\bullet(pt)} R
$$
and call $\rho_R$ Landweber exact in case this defines a cohomology theory. It is immmediate from the definition that if $\rho\colon A\to B$ is Landweber exact then $\rho(pt)\colon A^\bullet(pt)\to B^\bullet(pt)$ is Landweber exact. Also the vice versa is true and easily seen: if $C^\bullet$ is the cohomology theory defined by a Landweber exact morphism $\rho_{pt}$, then the comparison morphism $A^\bullet(X)\otimes_{A^\bullet(pt)}B^\bullet(pt)\to B^\bullet(X)$ is a morphism of cohomology theories $C^\bullet(X)\to B^\bullet(X)$that is an isomorphism over the point and so is an isomorphism for every finite CW complex. This gives an equivalence between Landweber exact ring spectra under $A$ and Landweber exact rings under $A^\bullet(pt)$, generalizing the calssical Landweber equivalence between Landweber exact ring spectra under $MU$ and Landweber exact rings under $MU^\bullet(pt)\cong \Omega^U$.

Now it comes the question. The classical Landweber exactness theorem is an algebraic characterization of Landweber exact rings under $MU^\bullet(pt)$ and is, ultimately, a theorem concerning the algebraic structure of the Hopf algebroid $(MU^\bullet(pt), MU^\bullet(MU^\vee))$, where $MU^\vee$ denotes the dual spectrum of $MU$ . So, at least in principle, an analogous algebraic characterization should be possible for $A^\bullet(pt)$-Landweber exact rings, and this could hopefully be something explicit if an explicit algebraic presentation of the Hopf algebroid $(A^\bullet(pt),A^\bullet(A^\vee))$ is known. Ideally, if such an algebraic criterion for Landweber exactness could be formulated, one could re-read, e.g., Hopkins-Hovey theorem on the spin cobordims determining real K-theory as the statement that $\hat{A}\colon MSpin(pt)\to KO(pt)$ satisfies the algebraic conditions for Landweber-exactness. And similarly for the other cases where such an exactness is know. So the question is:

- At which algebraic properties of $(A^\bullet(pt),A^\bullet(A^\vee))$ one should look at in order to formulate such a theorem?
- Are there other cases apart from the classical Landweber theorem where an algebraic characterization of Landweber exactness in the above sense has been given?

Comment: In the case of the Landweber exact functor theorem, the key object is not the ring $MU_*$, but rather the Hopf algebroid $(MU_*,MU_*MU)$. Therefore if such a general theorem is possible, I would expect it to hold for flat cohomology theories and the condition to be about the comodule structure over their Hopf algebroid.

Comment: Here are two other cases of this "Landweber-type" theorem. (Note that E_infinity-ness doesn't really have anything to do with Landweber exactness) The first is kind of trivial: take A = mod-2 homology (or homology with coeffs in any field). Then every A(pt)-module  R is flat and hence Landweber flat, and your rho_R is always a cohomology theory.

Comment: The second case is A=MO. That's slightly less trivial, since now A(pt) is a huge polynomial ring. It turns out that still every ring under A(pt) is Landweber flat. One way to say that is that the Hopf algebroid (MO_*, MO_*MO) has no invariant ideals, the other is that MO is actually just homology with MO_*-coefficients.

Comment: Denis and kiran, thanks for your comments! With your hints I now found the question is investigated in "Comodules and landweber exact homology theories" by Hovey and Strickland (https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0301232v1)

Answer (score 1):

Landweber exactness in the sense of the question is investigated in detail in [Comodules and Landweber exact homology theories](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0301232v1), by Mark Hovey and Neil Strickland.